# Moving element outside of grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, web-frontend

I'm developing a tumblr theme with bootstrap, and I'd like a nice big area for the user's profile picture right next to the header. The issue here is, that bootstrap has a very tight grid format and I can't see any room for what I want:

[image]

see that red thing? I want to move it where the blue arrow is pointing. I've tried expanding the container, setting the red circle to float left, and giving it margin-bottom:100%, but that shoved everything down off the page.

Here's my css and HTML for reference, the item in question is labeled with the class "talkbubble":

*CSS*

```
//Media Queries
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .container {
        width: 800px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .container {
        width: 800px;
    }
}


//Header Edits
.jumbotron{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    h1{
        color: red;
    }
}   

//upsidedown tab edits
.tab-content{
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:0px;
}
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:-1px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    width: 71px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-color: #eee;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
}
.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    cursor: default; 
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    background-color: #eee !important;
}

.arrow {
    border-color: #eee transparent transparent #eee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2px;
    right:-33px;

}

.arrow2 {
    border-color: #eee #eee transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2px;
    right:67px;

}


//square gallery
.square{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

//iconbubble

.talkbubble {
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   -moz-border-radius: 60px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
   border-radius: 60px;
} 
.talkbubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   right: 100%;
   top: 50px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid red;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
```

*HTML below*

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
     <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fakecrop.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>


  <body data-pinterest-extension-installed="cr1.39.1">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="talkbubble"></div>
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <!--
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        -->
        <h3 class="text-muted">Hi I'm...</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h1>CpBunni</h1>
        <p class="lead">...and I'm an artist.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>CpBunni</h1>
        <p class="lead">...and I'm a cosplayer.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>CpBunni</h1>
        <p class="lead">...and I'm a nude model.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home <div class="arrow"></div><div class="arrow2"></div></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1 <div class="arrow"></div><div class="arrow2"></div></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2 <div class="arrow"></div><div class="arrow2"></div></a></li>
      </ul>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // for a filled square thumbnail
            $('.square img').fakecrop({fill: true, wrapperWidth: 200, wrapperHeight: 200});
        });
    </script>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg.jpg" alt="..."></div></a> 
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg2.jpg" alt="..."></div></a>  
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg3.jpg" alt="..."></div></a>  
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg4.png" alt="..."></div></a>  

        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg5.jpg" alt="..."></div></a>  

        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>© 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>
       </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="./Narrow Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap_files/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <div id="scrollrail-vertical" class="disabled" style="width: 12px; border-left-width: 1px;"><div id="scrollbar-vertical" style="visibility: hidden; border-radius: 5px 7px; box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.901961) 0px 0px 1px 1px; height: 1015px; top: 2px; opacity: 0;"></div></div><div id="scrollrail-horizontal" class="disabled" style="height: 12px; border-top-width: 1px;"><div id="scrollbar-horizontal" style="visibility: hidden; border-radius: 14px 10px; box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.901961) 0px 0px 1px 1px; width: 1916px; left: 2px; opacity: 0;"></div></div><div id="window-resizer-tooltip"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#" title="Edit settings"></a><span class="tooltipTitle">Window size: </span><span class="tooltipWidth" id="winWidth"></span> x <span class="tooltipHeight" id="winHeight"></span><br><span class="tooltipTitle">Viewport size: </span><span class="tooltipWidth" id="vpWidth"></span> x <span class="tooltipHeight" id="vpHeight"></span></div></body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/137Ldxpv/)

The trick is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      ...your image markup here...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've set it to be like that from `md` up. You might want to make use of `hidden-*` for the image column at lower widths as what you're doing from a design point of view would look strange at mobile widths.

Comment: This worked like a charm and also allowed me to not have to break bootstrap's system to do so. :) Perfect! The issue here was that I didn't really understand bootstrap's grid system. The numbers in the "col-md-xx" have to add up to 12, so creating two columns of 3 and 9 gives me a small area to put my profile image undisturbed.

Comment: @bryanwillis7 yes that's right. I had wondered if you had fully grasped the grid system - if you would like me to further clarify in the answer any points I can expand on it. But it is good that you've found that out yourself. For 3-9, that makes the image sit at a quarter width. The reason the grid is 12 is because it divides so well.

Comment: One thing I did notice is that you might make it worth your time just to read through the documentation on bootstrap from start to finish. You may find that you are trying to do various things in CSS/javascript that bootstrap already has covered. Note: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images `<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-rounded">` for your rounded images

Answer (score 1):

1. The absolute position is a right way for your issue. But you have to use another properties instead of `float`:

   - [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top)
   - [`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)
   - [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/left)
   - [`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/right)

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the margin edge of the element and the edge of its containing block.
>
> For relatively positioned elements (those with position: relative), it specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position.

2. You can apply this properties directly to the bubble instead of the `before:` pseudo-element.
3. Use `/*  */` instead of `//` for comments in CSS. For example:

```
/* iconbubble */
.talkbubble {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Please check the result:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Media Queries */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

/* Header Edits */
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}

/* upsidedown tab edits */
.tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  width: 71px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #eee;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.nav-tabs > .active > a,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  background-color: #eee !important;
}
.arrow {
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent #eee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: -33px;
}
.arrow2 {
  border-color: #eee #eee transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 67px;
}

/* square gallery */
.square {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

/* iconbubble */
.talkbubble {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
.talkbubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 26px solid red;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="talkbubble"></div>
  <div class="header clearfix">
    <!--
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    -->
    <h3 class="text-muted">Hi I'm...</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h1>CpBunni</h1>
      <p class="lead">...and I'm an artist.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h1>CpBunni</h1>
      <p class="lead">...and I'm a cosplayer.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h1>CpBunni</h1>
      <p class="lead">...and I'm a nude model.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home <div class="arrow"></div><div class="arrow2"></div></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1 <div class="arrow"></div><div class="arrow2"></div></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2 <div class="arrow"></div><div class="arrow2"></div></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg.jpg" alt="..."></div></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg2.jpg" alt="..."></div></a>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg3.jpg" alt="..."></div></a>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg4.png" alt="..."></div></a>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#"><div class="square"><img src="resources/testimg5.jpg" alt="..."></div></a>  
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <p>© 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
  </footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Hm I tried it and the header is still wanting to dip below my talk bubble instead of sit next to it.  I've also tried adding both float and display: block and neither worked

Comment: @bryanwillis7 The absolute position is a right way for your issue. But you have to use another properties instead of `float`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So while this did work exactly as I wanted, it ended up causing a few more problems. Mainly dealing with responsiveness. Also, I'm using SASS, I completely forgot to mention that. My bad