# how to place an element on top of existing container using css-grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, z-index

I have a page with a grid container which
I want to add a parent element (cookie consent element)
between buttom of component two and footer
like in the added screenshot
which is not affected by the grid layout

considering this similar question and answer
[Moving element outside of grid system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37897349/14725238)

which suggest to use `position: absolute`

```
  .cookie-consent {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    /* top: 300px;
    left: 30px;
     bottom: 100px; */
    
    z-index: 20;
  }
```

is there a better way to place the div
without using trial and error  `top` , `left` , `right` parameters til the desired position is reached ?

[image: element on top of grid layout]

```css
:root {
   
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
  }
  

  .container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.2fr 1.8fr 0.3fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav nav nav nav"
      "component1 component1 component1 component1"
      "component2 component2 component2 component2"
      "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  
    text-align: center;
  }
  


  nav {
    text-align: center;
    background: #a7ffeb;
    grid-area: nav;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  


  
  #component1 {
    background: #6fffd2;
    grid-area: component1;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  #component2 {
    background: #64ffda;
    grid-area: component2;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  




  
  footer {
    background: #1de9b6;
    grid-area: footer;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  .cookie-consent {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    /* top: 300px;
    left: 30px;
     bottom: 100px; */
    
    z-index: 20;
  }

  /* place the element cookie on top of the gird layout */
  /*  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- add style css to page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cookie-consent">cookies</div>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>Navbar</nav>
      <div id="component1">component1</div>
      <div id="component2">component2</div>
    
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have a scrolling application, use `position: fixed / sticky`.  In a full screen application,  you can place between *component2* and *footer* with `grid-template-rows`.

Comment: Where do you want it to be positioned - for example at the top of the viewport but centered horizontally or...?

Comment: at the red square position in the screenshot

Comment: Please upvote the answer below if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

First to ensure that the `cookie consent element` style inline with the container class element, ensure that all the contents are in a similar container: After adding the container element, your HTML file should look like the one below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <!-- add style css to page -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

     <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="cookie-consent">cookies</div>
      <div class="container">
        <nav>Navbar</nav>
        <div id="component1">component1</div>
        <div id="component2">component2</div>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
     </div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then remove the position absolute from your CSS on the `cookie consent element` to ensure that you maintain a uniform flow. After removing the positioning, your `cookie consent element` style should look like the one below:

```
.cookie-consent {
   background: red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 80px;
   margin: auto;
   z-index: 20;
}
```

This will help move the element ontop of the grid container.